# G3100 Fios WiFi 6 Router

Tags: networking, ip, routing, fios

Is it possible to change the local IP address on a Verizon G3100 Fios Wifi 6 router from 192.168.x.x to 172.17.x.x or 10.0.x.x
I have gone into Network, Network Connection, clicked edit on home/Office, then I click on Settings at the bottom of the page which brings up the the Properties page, I change the IP Address to 172.18.x.x and the Subnet Mask to 255.255.255.128 then I go down the page to the DHCP Server section and enter a Start IP Address of 172.18.1.2  and an end IP Address of 172.18.1.126 I click Apply and give the router a few minutes and when I try to connect either thru ethernet or to the SSID I can't connect and have to reset the router to factory default. I have tried 3 times no luck. Is it not possible to change the IP of the network? if so wyy is 192.168.x.x the only IP range allowed?

Comment: Did you ask Verizon Support whether this can be done?  They may have set all their router to the same basic settings for manageability. You may need to add your own good router for you own network flexibility.

Comment: A screen shot would be helpfull

Comment: We can change them here in PA, they don't lock you out of anything in the firmware that I am aware of. It sounds like your router has a problem commiting nv_ram changes. (This would mean it's defective) try adding a port-forward rule in the firewall, does it commit? If the answer is no, it's time to call VZ and have it replaced!